# .htaccess - load index.php when no specific word otherwise other file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to load `index.php` by default **BUT** if there is `call` or `call.php` in url it should load **call.php** file instead:

**Default URL (below URLs should load ROOT/index.php):**

```
http://example.com/rgt-cfjv-vlm
http://example.com/index.php/rgt-cfjv-vlm
```

**Other URL (below URLs should load ROOT/call.php):**

```
http://example.com/call/rgt-cfjv-vlm
http://example.com/call.php/rgt-cfjv-vlm
```

> **NOTE "rgt-cfjv-vlm" is a random string and it will always come in URL**

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: apache Alias (Alias "/call" and followed by Directory where you can put DirectoryIndex as call.php ) that will also work

Comment: @TranquillityI don't have access to apache setting bro

Answer (score 1):

here you go:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} call
RewriteRule .* call.php 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !call
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Comment: with this htaccess, its loading  call.php always with both urls. i.e. `http://example.com/rgt-cfjv-vlm and http://example.com/index.php/rgt-cfjv-vlm`

Comment: It should not. Have you added "!" in the second condition.  first condition is if the URL contains call then load call.php  second condition is if it does not then call index.php.  I have tested it already.  Is there any other redirections in your htaccess as well ?

Comment: I'm using your provided .htaccess as it is. And no there is no extra code in my .htaccess but still its loading call.php by anymean

Comment: [link]https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ . Copy my htaccess over here and write your urls to test: http://example.com/index.php/rgt-cfjv-vlm or http://example.com/call/rgt-cfjv-vlm or anything else.

Comment: [.htaccess Shareable URL](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=4e4b4f86-32ee-513f-b905-cf72278301f5) please check, its localhost shareable url there via **ngrok**

Comment: Yes just checked, so its working right?. remove the word "call" from your url and it will take to index.php.. See here: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/?share=1976b80d-7c9d-5578-9a89-cec4f8a3efe8

Comment: According to "htaccess.madewithlove.be" its right! But when I'm using it actual its always loading **call.php** and there's no extra .htaccess. I don't know what's wrong..

Comment: Since the online tool marking this solution correct, upvoting this answer. Really appreciate your help @Jawad Khan

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround:**
I have changed my directory structure as below:

**For Default URL (http://example.com/rgt-cfjv-vlm):**

> ROOT/index.php

**ROOT/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,QSA]
```

**For Other URL (http://example.com/call/rgt-cfjv-vlm):**

> ROOT/call/index.php

**ROOT/call/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,QSA]
```

Now its loading **ROOT/index.php** on `http://example.com/rgt-cfjv-vlm` and **ROOT/call/index.php** on `http://example.com/call/rgt-cfjv-vlm`.

***I believe there will be some better solution but using it on temporary bases.***